# How does this date and time snippet work?

Tags: java, date, time, date-format, simpledateformat

I just started taking a computer science class a week ago, and I found this code to get the date and time. But I don't fully understand what everything in this means. If anyone could clarify that would be awesome! :)

```
long yourmilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");    
Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);
System.out.print("Date: ");
System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`long yourmilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();`

get the number of milliseconds from the System

`Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);`

Creates a date from it.  These two lines could be changed to

`Date resultdate = new Date();`

As dates in JDK1.7 and previous did not have any intrinsic formatting a formatting class is used

`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");`

This is the pattern it will print as

`System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));`

Now we call the formatting method and print it out.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Scary Wombat did a good job explaining the individual steps to you, but there is a bit more to it.

First of all, learning programming is about making experiences **yourself**. So, your first step to approach this would be: take that source code, and instead of pasting it into a SO question ... paste it into a "public static void main" method; within a public class; compile it, run it, and see what happens. And start playing around with it.

If that leaves you with questions, the next step would be to lookup javadoc - you see; all your code deals with **standard** classes; and they are all well [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

So, lesson for today: asking here is OK, but make sure that you really *try* to figure such things yourself first! Not only because the policy of this site says so, but because that gives you the **most** learning results out of your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

That code:

- Captures the current moment (date-time)
- Generates a String to textually represent that moment.

Note that these are two distinct concepts. A date-time object is *not* a String. A date-time object *generates* a String to represent its value. Novice programmers often conflate the two causing much confusion and frustration.

Unfortunately that code snippet uses some old legacy date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes. The old classes have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome.

The modern way to capture the current moment is simple. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment in the timeline in UTC with a resolution up to nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

To generate a String that represents that moment in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, simply call `toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2016-09-12T05:36:55Z

Adjust into a particular time zone (`ZoneId`) to see the same moment through the lens of that region’s wall-clock time.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Again, to generate a String that represents that moment in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, simply call `toString`. Actually, the [`ZonedDateTime`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) extends the standard by wisely appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString();
```

> 2016-09-12T01:36:55-04:00[America/Montreal]

To generate Strings in other formats, search Stack Overflow for the java.time class `DateTimeFormatter`.